# Android - attach data to views

Tags: android, android-widget

In my application I create dynamic rows in table much as in this tutorial:
http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout

```
 for(int i = startDay; i < startDay + 7; i++){

      /* Create a TextView to be the row-content. */
      TextView day = new TextView(this);
      day.setText(Integer.toString(i));
      day.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      day.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.i("Listener: ", "Click");
          }
```

So now when I click on a TextView I can register click event, but how do I determine which TextView was clicked?

Not just an object which I get with an event but data like which day number was clicked?

Ideally I would want to have data attached to every view I create dynamically.
Something like data() method in Javascript jQuery.

Right now I can see only 1 way to solve this - while creating TextView add id with data and when clicked - get id back and parse it to get my data. But it strikes me as ugly approach.

Is there a way to attach arbitrary data to android views?

Answer (score 63):

Found answer going through view methods. Maybe it will be useful for someone.

Methods I needed were:

setTag() and getTag()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: what happens if I need several data ? not just one tag ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales You can add several tags, each identified by an int key.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales You can add a list of unique object identifiers to the tag.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales or you can use some collection, like `HashMap<Key, Val>`